# Calling Stored Procedure From Entity Framework that returns table with variable columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and EF 4.x

I have a procedure that returns a result set but the columns are not fixed (it may return 25 columns or may be 40 or 50).

How can I call this stored procedure from Entity Framework?

When I use function import it asks for an Entity. But I cannot select it as none of the columns is fixed.

Comment: Try to create entity that contains all of the possible columns that can be returned and have all of the fields non required. Use that entity when you import it and it should work.

Comment: How this returned data will be used to create new object? Will you choose the correct entity by counting the number of columns?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is not the right tool for this. It is good at statically defined data structures, not at dynamic ones.

There are better tools for this. I would recommend [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), created by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell). It's easy as pie. Just get the NuGet package and type something like

```
using Dapper;

using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    cnn.Open();
    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@params", "Id=21");
    var results = cnn.Query(sql:"GetMyData",
                            param: p, 
                            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    foreach(IDictionary<string, object> result in results)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

`Query` is a Dapper extension method, `result` is a `DapperRow`, which is a private class that implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can just access your data as a dictionary per record.

Aside from being easy to use, it's lightning fast too.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why anyone would downvote this. Is it because I don't answer the question literally? Well, there is *no way* to do this with EF.